# Send a file of any type via C socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to write a server-client program in C. Is it possible for the server to send a file of any type(.mp3, .doc etc) to the client? Are there any links or references? Or any libraries? I haven't found anything.

Comment: It's at a lower level, but yes. It's used in the building blocks of how the internet works.

Comment: C doesn't care about the file type. Just read the bytes from the file and write them to the network.

Comment: I've tried with 'sendfile()' but I had some problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reading http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ and also understand how TCP/IP works at least basically. Sending a file is not much more different than sending a text and etc. There is simple example on http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/csobaniec/examples/sockets/. Simply read bytes from a file and send them via BSD sockets. When you examine the example above, you will see how basic it is.